# DJANGO: How to get list of filenames in views.py on server?

Tags: python, django, static

I'm trying to get a list of filenames of static files in views.py.
I did this: `img_names = listdir('static/images/avatars')` on my computer and it worked, but it doesn't work on server. Also some other solutions doesn't work, like:

```
from django.templatetags.static import static
img_names = listdir(static(/images/avatars'))
```

I constantly get this error:

```
FileNotFoundError at /user/new/
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'static/images/avatars'
```

Although when I type myadress/static/images/avatars/example.png the photo displays.
How can I fix it? Or maybe there's a different way to programatically create some objects from a folder based on it's contest...

```
settings.py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),)
```

Comment: Did you find answer? Though you need to make that path to be accessible in application server config file. Then you can access those dirs. this is not best practice to access those dir. But your requirement is so go ahead.

Comment: Where do I change application server config file?

Comment: What application server are you using?

Comment: pythonanywhere.com

Comment: This is first time I have heard of that, you need to find out what is the location of config files.

Comment: And you should follow the duplicate thread mentioned above. That is in detailed

Comment: I'll do this another way but thanks...